# Import data to local SSD volume in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am setting up an instance (on Google Cloud Platform) with `100GB boot disk` and a `local SSD`. My data is roughly `150GB`. When I import this data, I get insufficient memory error. When I increase my boot disk size to `200GB`, there's no error.

I think that the data is being written on the Boot disk as opposed to the `local SSD`. How do I ensure that it is the `local SSD` that has the data stored on it and not the `boot disk`?

[EDIT] I am mounting the ssd using the [lsblk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#formatandmount) Bit unclear on what [MNT_DIR] should be in 
`sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]`
My data gets imported to `/home/jupyter/`

Comment: Show where you mounted the local SSD. Show the command you are using to copy data. If you want your data copied to /home/jupyter, then you need to mount the SSD at that mount point.

Comment: Hi, John. I got it. This is what I was doing wrong. Mounted the SSD to some folder and importing data in some other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an instance with a local SSD, the disk itself isn't mounted yet, you'll need to create a filesystem on it and mount it (in linux you can see the mounted disk by running `lsblk`).

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#formatindividual

This doc explains how to mount a single local ssd and how to create a RAID array if you like to mount multiple local SSDs.

From comments -

Yes, you should import your data into the folder you've mounted your disk, but IMHO I wouldn't use home for that, I think it's best practice to mount all external disks into "/mnt" (so "/mnt/vol", "/mnt/vol1", or something like that). If you'll use /home you'll "shadow" to current files exists in this dir.

Comment: Yes, I followed the link to mount the disk. what is the [MNT_DIR] here -
```sudo mount /dev/[SSD_NAME] /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR] ```
Any random name? or should it be ```/home/jupyter``` - where my data gets stored after importing?

Comment: Yes, you should import your data into the folder you've mounted your disk, but IMHO I wouldn't use home for that, I think it's best practice to mount all external disks into "/mnt" (so "/mnt/vol", "/mnt/vol1", or something like that).
If you'll use /home you'll "shadow" to current files exists in this dir.

Comment: Oh didn't know about 'shadowing'. Any link which explains this further + what files should then be kept here? So I should directly import the data to ```/mnt/disks/ssd1``` as opposed to ```/home/jupyter```?

Comment: Shadowing means the files will just be invisible from the filesystem, but the data itself still be there, so once you unmount the disk you'll have access to it again (https://askubuntu.com/a/11270), so if you mount on it and save files, they'll be saved on the disk you mounted, but you'll not have access to the files on the boot disk (in this specific location).
You should mount your disk on an empty directory and save the files there.

Comment: hey, thanks, storing the data on the mounted SSD works!